# Check if the sum of 2 numbers in a list is present in another list in python

Tags: python

I have two lists. The first one is the numbers the computer can choose from to get one of the `end_result` numbers. I have tried different ways of making this work, and none of them seem to work. I always get the error `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'`. I can't subtract an `int` from a `list`. This question is basically asking another way to do this. Help is appreciated.

```python
lst_choice = [1, 6, 7, 3, 8, 9, 2]
end_result = [5, 2, 7, 4, 9, 14]

for i, num in enumerate(lst_choice [:-1]):
    comp = end_result - num
    if comp in lst_choice [i+1:]:
        print("The two numbers are", num, "and", comp)
        break
else:
    print("There are no solutions")
```

Comment: Please post more code showing what you have already tried.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Two numbers from the lst_choice sums to one of the end_result in the list.

Comment: This is where I get the TypeError

Comment: You cannot use the whole list, you have to choose one element from the list.
Check out this article, its about all the things you can do to lists:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp

Comment: Is there a way to make a for loop that goes through each number in the list.

Comment: Yes, search it up on Google. it's like this:
for number in end_result:
    print(number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using list comprehension like so:

```
allSums = [lst_choice[x]+y for x in range(len(lst_choice)) for y in lst_choice[x+1:]]
allSumNums = [(lst_choice[x], y) for x in range(len(lst_choice)) for y in lst_choice[x+1:]]

if(list(set(allSums) & set(end_result)) == []):
    print('no solutions exist')
else:
    for x, y in allSumNums:
        print('The 2 numbers are', x, y)
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Comment: this seems to be adding two numbers from the list that aren't there

Comment: like 7 and 7 or 1 and 1 or 8 and 8

Comment: Let me check into that

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've changed the function. It works as expected now!

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I've been trying to make this work for this whole weekend.

Comment: I think I did. Is it the check mark or the arrow. I did both.